# Apply parent mouse events to child elements

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, custom-controls, parent

I am making little Windows Forms Application.
I have PictureBox (parent) and Label (child) in it.

The Parent's Mouse Events are working perfectly, but Mouse events generated by child elements are not reflected on the Parent. The Cursor also changes back to its default (arrow).

Is it possible to *pass* events generated by child Controls, e.g., the `MouseEnter` event, to the Parent Control?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Card.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(Card_MouseEnter);
        Card.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(Card_MouseLeave);
        Card.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.Card_MouseDown);
        Card.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(this.Card_MouseUp);
    }

    void Card_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Card.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.card_bg));
        this.Rename("Running!");
    }

    void Card_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Card.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.card_hover_bg));
    }

    private void Card_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Card.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.card_click_bg));
    }

    private void Card_MouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Card.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.card_hover_bg));
        this.Rename("Please Wait...");
    }

    private void CardName_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    void Rename(string args)
    {
        this.CardName.Text = args;
    }

    private void CardName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

[image]

[image: elements in designer]

[image: This is what I have]         [image: And this is what I want to achieve]

```
            This is what I have                       This is what I want to achieve
```

The first animation represents what I have now, the second is what I need to achieve :)

Comment: Develop a USERCONTROL with that PictureBox and Label inside it.  Then you can define your own CUSTOM EVENTS that only get raised when you want them to (instead of using the canned `MouseLeave`, etc. events).  When  the PictureBox gets a MouseLeave event, you can check the cursor position to see if it is still within the bounds of the PictureBox (meaning it entered the Label).  Raise your custom "leave" event only when the cursor is actually outside of the PictureBox in the MouseLeave event.

Comment: Have you tried to call `Card_MouseEnter(Card, e);` in the Label's MouseEnter event? Btw, you could simply paint that text and change the cursor or perform other actions when the Mouse pointer enters a specific area of the PictureBox (or the UserControl or whatever). You can use `Rectangle.Contains(Point)` for that.

Comment: BTW2, I'm assuming you have set the Label's Parent to the PictureBox, not just moved the Label on top of it.

Comment: How did you make the Label a "child" of the PictureBox?  If it is simply on top of the PB, then the cursor will change as you leave the PB and enter the Label.  If you make the Label an actual CHILD with `pictureBox1.Controls.Add(label1)`, then the cursor stays the same when you move from the PB to the Label.

Comment: Oh people let me try parent it to child  because I really moved just top of it, silly me :P

Comment: If you position it in the designer, you can parent it in the `Load()` event using code like this to keep it in the same place: (1) `Point pt = this.PointToScreen(label1.Location);` (2) `pictureBox1.Controls.Add(label1);` (3) `label1.Location = pictureBox1.PointToClient(pt);`.

Comment: BTW3, you can also subscribe to the Label's `MouseEnter` and `MouseClick` or `Click` using the same handlers used for the PictureBox events. `MouseLeave` is not required for the Label, since the Parent will raise the event anyway. Unless you want a different handler for the Label's `Click/MouseClick` events. In this case, use distinct handlers to perform different actions.

Comment: I tried to put Card.Controls.Add(CardName); but it disappears...
I tried  Idle_Mind's idea too, it has no errors but it's same, nothing changed

Comment: After you've set the Parent, just write `CardName.Location = new Point(0, Card.Height - CardName.Height); CardName.BringToFront();` (or what Idle_Mind posted, what matters is that you have to relocate the Label, since its position is now relative to the new Parent - It's usually better to also `BringToFront()` the child control, since the PictureBox is not a ContainerControl).

Comment: Thank you for answers. After many hours struggling couldn't done anything. Only worked Jimi's idea ""Have you tried to call Card_MouseEnter(Card, e);"" This is not exactly what I need here but that is close. Problem is that now I can't use label's MouseEvents. When I'm making pictureBox1.Controls.Add(label1) label1 is disappearing and I tried bring to front and change color but couldn't do it. Please if you will have any idea show me in provided code by me to be understandable for me. Thank you all again and again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I'm making pictureBox1.Controls.Add(label1) label1 is
> disappearing and I tried bring to front and change color but couldn't
> do it. Please if you will have any idea show me in provided code by me
> to be understandable for me. Thank you all again and again :)

You'd use code like this, maybe in the Load() event of the Form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point pt = CardName.Parent.PointToScreen(CardName.Location);
    Card.Controls.Add(CardName);
    CardName.Location = Card.PointToClient(pt);
}
```

This keeps the label in the same position as it was, but makes the picturebox the parent.

Not sure where you're going wrong.  Here's an example showing it in action.  Both the PictureBox (Card) and Label (CardName) are inside a Panel (panel1).  Clicking on button2 toggles the visibility of the Card.  Clicking on button1 makes Card the Parent of CardName.  You can see that at first, only the Card toggles visibility, but after clicking on button1 and setting the Parent, both toggle visibility together since CardName is a Child of Card (it also changes its BackColor to match that of its new Parent):

[image]

Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = CardName.Parent.PointToScreen(CardName.Location);
        Card.Controls.Add(CardName);
        CardName.Location = Card.PointToClient(pt);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Card.Visible = !Card.Visible;
    }

}
```

> When I move mouse over label, panel thinks mouse left it and rises
> MouseLeave event

Here is how you can tell if the cursor has actually left the BOUNDS of the Panel, as opposed to simply enter a child control within the Panel:

```
private void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point pt = panel1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    if (!panel1.ClientRectangle.Contains(pt))
    {
        // we only get in here when the cursor leaves the BOUNDS of panel1
        panel1.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
    }            
}
```

Comment: I tried that before when you told me in the comments, but it really is not working :'(

Comment: Please post a picture of the Form, in the designer, with the PictureBox and the Label.

Comment: I posted it please see it

Comment: Sorry I am making as you told, but it's not working. May be my explanation was confusing, so I added gif in description please see it maybe it will be less confusing

Comment: The only code I needed to make the cursor stay on BOTH of them was: `Card.Cursor = Cursors.Hand` (or assign it only to the Card via the IDE).  Once the CardName (label) was correctly assigned as a Child of the Card, it automatically took on the Hand cursor as well.  Is there are good reason for keeping the PictureBox, instead of using a PANEL?  You can assign a image to the panel AND have children without needing code...

Comment: Ok you were right about changing PictureBox to Panel, label automatically was assigned to Panel and Cursors.Hand is working but hover effect still is the problem. :'(

Comment: K...so you have the Label in a Panel and Cursor is fixed.  Explain the "hover" problem again.

Comment: When I move mouse over label, panel thinks mouse left it and rises MouseLeave event

Comment: See code at the bottom to determine when a MouseLeave() event means that the cursor actually left the BOUNDS of the Panel.

Comment: That 's it! your last code was exactly what I needed. Now it is working correctly. I rebuilt whole project under UserControl due to Jimi's answer because he really has point, but as this is exact solution what I asked originally I have to select this as accepted answer.

Comment: Glad you figured it out finally.  Feel free to upvote ANY post that was helpful in your journey.  ;)

Comment: Thank you. you really helped me so much ^.^

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should build a UserControl as a container for all your objects: it'd make everything simpler (the one I'm using here is actually a UserControl, modified to comply with your current setup).

When a Control other than the PictureBox is interacted with, you can decide whether you want to trigger a similar action on the main Control or perform a different action based on what event has been generated.

▶ When the Mouse Pointer enters you *assembled* Control, you want to change the default Cursor: then, when one of the Labels raises the `Enter` event, call the method of the main Control that handles this. An event handler is a method, you can call it.

▶ When a Label is clicked, you **don't want** to trigger the related action of the main Control: in this case, there's nothing to do, just handle this event and perform the required action.

▶ The Label should be child of the main Control. You're using a PictureBox, which is not a ContainerControl. You can add child controls to it anyway. You need to do this in code, since - as mentioned - the PictureBox is not designed to host Controls, thus you cannot drop one *inside* it: the Control you drop will be parented with the Container that hosts the PictureBox (your Form, here).
When you set the parent in code, you need to remember that the Location of the child control is relative to the old Parent, so you have to re-define it's position.

E.g:  `PictureBox.Bounds = (100, 100, 100, 200)` / `Label.Bounds = (100, 250, 100, 50)`

When the PictureBox becomes Parent of your Label, the `Label.Location` is still `(100, 250)`: so, now, it will be *hidden*, since it's outside the visible bounds of its new Parent.  You have to reposition it in relation to the new host: its new Location should be `(0, 150)`, to keep the previous relative position.

```
PictureBox.Control.Add(Label);
//[...]
Label.Location = new Point(Label.Left - PictureBox.Left, Label.Top - PictureBox.Top);
=> Label.Location = (100 - 100, 250 - 100) => (0, 150)
```

Or, centered horizontally:

```
Label.Location = new Point((PictureBox.Width - Label.Width) / 2, Label.Top - PictureBox.Top);
=> Label.Location = ((100 - 100) / 2, 250 - 100) => (0, 150) // <- Since both have the same Width
```

Or, using positions relative to the Screen:

```
var p = Label.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);  // Relative to the ClientRectangle (Top/Left = (0, 0))
PictureBox.Controls.Add(Label);
Label.Location = PictureBox.PointToClient(p);
```

In any case, call `BringToFront()` after, to ensure that the new child Control is brought on top and anchor the Control, so it will keep its position and its Width will be bound to the Parent Width:

```
Label.BringToFront();
Label.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
```

Now, assuming you want to change the Cursor to `Cursors.Hand` when the Mouse enters your *combined Control* and reset to default when it leaves it:

▶ You want the Cursor to change shape in any case.
▶ You want to generate different actions when the PictureBox is clicked and when one of the Labels is clicked.
▶ Both Labels can have distinct actions when clicked.

[image: UserControl Mixed Event Handlers]

→ <sub>In the visual sample, the Label above the PictureBox is named **`lblTitle`**, the Label *inside* the PictureBox, at the bottom, is named **`lblFooter`**</sub>.
→ <sub>The PictureBox is named **`ImageView`**</sub>.

Setup the handlers:

NOTE: With a UserControl, the events handling, e.g., in relation to MouseEnter, changes in:

```
// The Parent's MouseEnter calls OnMouseEnter
protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}

// Child Controls just call the same method
private void Labels_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) => OnMouseEnter(e);
```

---

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

        Point p = lblFooter.PointToScreen(Point.Empty); 
        ImageView.Controls.Add(lblFooter);
        lblFooter.Location = ImageView.PointToClient(p);

        ImageView_MouseEnter += ImageView_MouseEnter;
        ImageView_MouseLeave += ImageView_MouseLeave;
        // Not added in the code here, do whatever is needed with this handler
        ImageView_Click += ImageView_Click;

        lblFooter.MouseEnter += Labels_MouseEnter;
        lblFooter.MouseLeave += Labels_MouseLeave;
        lblFooter.MouseClick += lblFooter_MouseClick;

        lblTitle.MouseEnter += Labels_MouseEnter;
        lblTitle.MouseLeave += Labels_MouseLeave;
        lblTitle.MouseDown += lblTitle_MouseDown;
        lblTitle.MouseUp += lblTitle_MouseUp;
}

private void ImageView_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) => this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

private void ImageView_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) => this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

private void Labels_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageView_MouseEnter(ImageView, e);
    // [...]
    // Do stuff related to the Labels Enter event
}

private void Labels_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ImageView_MouseLeave(ImageView, e);
}

private void lblTitle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    // Perform actions when the Mouse button is held down lblTitle
}

private void lblTitle_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    // Perform actions when the Mouse button is released
}

private void lblFooter_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    // Perform actions on a Mouse Click event on lblFooter
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jimi for your answer. I rebuilt my whole project under UserControl  because of your answer and really it is correct way to go. But as Idle_Mind's answer exactly meets my old code posted here, his answer should be selected as final. Thank you again you helped me so much :)

Comment: Sure. Glad it helped :)