# How to do Rounded and Drop Shadowed in WinForm Controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dropshadow

I've looked at a few resources, but haven't been able to find the exact answer to this question. How can I make drop shadowed and rounded control like the example below?

[image]

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: With a UserControl + custom painting + inflated Region. See, e.g., the Control with the doggie image [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62925411/7444103); it's a visual sample for something else, there's no code to reproduce it, but the core functionality is shown here [How to avoid visual artifacts of colored border of zoomable UserControl with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794097/7444103)

Comment: This might be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38632035/winforms-smooth-the-rounded-edges-for-panel